# gdb reports: " Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)", when viewing backtrace

Tags: linux, arm, gdb

I'm debugging a multithreaded application on an ARM-processor,
running Linux.

When I attach to my application with gdb, I find some of the
threads are waiting to enter a critical section guarded by a
mutex: they've called pthread_mutex_lock() & are stalled in the
kernel in futex_lock_pi.isra.9

gdb's backtrace displays these just fine:-

```
(gdb) bt  
#0  0x4f4b4378 in ?? ()  
#1  0x0184c2cc in pt::mutex::pt_enter (this=0x24bc3a8 <linx::LCMNode::m_Lock>) at pthread.cxx:414  
#2  0x0184c8cc in pt::mutex::enter (this=0x24bc3a8 <linx::LCMNode::m_Lock>) at pthread.cxx:717  
#3  0x0184a800 in pt::rwlock::rdlock (this=0x24bc3a8 <linx::LCMNode::m_Lock>) at prwlock.cxx:128  
#4  0x01749544 in linx::LCMNode::ReadLock (this=0x2fddd1a0) at src/MNode.cpp:411  
#5  0x017796ac in linx::LCMVar<bool>::GetValue (this=0x2fddd1a0, Transaction=...) at ../../src/ManagedObjects/include/MVar_TemplateDefinition.hpp:324
```

Which is dandy.

But other threads use pthreads-lib in different ways: e.g. some have called pthread_cond_wait() & wound up stalled in the
kernel in futex_wait_queue_me

For these, I can't get a backtrace from gdb:-

```
(gdb) thread 45  
[Switching to thread 45 (Thread 909)]  
#0  0x4f4bb930 in ?? ()  
(gdb) bt  
#0  0x4f4bb930 in ?? ()  
#1  0x4f4bb914 in ?? ()  
#2  0x4f4bb914 in ?? ()  
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Is there anything I might do, can anyone say, to wrangle a
backtrace out of gdb for these threads? -- TIA, s.

Comment: Examine the `PC` value in `thread 45`; what routine is it near?  It is possible for a compiler to use `fp` was a general purpose register.  GDB may try to use it as a stack frame.  Not all code (including shared libraries) maybe compiled in a way that GDB is able to trace stacks.

Comment: > Examine the PC value in thread 45; what routine is it near?

-- gdb isn't forthcoming about that; prob' because pc is in kernel -- But I'm happy to believe it's in mutex_wait_queue_me(), as gleaned from /proc/<thread>.

Comment: > It is possible for a compiler to use fp was a general purpose register. GDB may try to use it as a stack frame.

 -- Yes, I've been trying to coerce gdb into picking backtrace up from further back in the stack, as described in http://fragglet.livejournal.com/19646.html. But I find fiddling with sp (or fp [R11] for that matter) has no effect on bt. Suspect more cunning required on ARM -- Involving lr perhaps? Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can not get a stack trace on a corruption.  You can just examine `lr` with `info registers`.  If you type `dis $lr`, `x/i $pc` and `p/x $sp` can all be helpful...  You need to get the last known sane function (leaf) and put a breakpoint there.  Check the address range is `/proc/self/maps` to see what library, etc it is in.  GDB can not trace things if it doesn't have sufficient information and/or the code is abnormal to the EABI.  Functions can be two types; entry/exit preserve EABI or the entire function adheres to EABI.  A kernel call might be the first type.